# Spring Boot serialize text/javascript to JSON

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-rest

I created the following Kotlin data class:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public data class ITunesArtist(val artistName: String, 
    val artistId: Long, val artistLinkUrl: URL)
```

*(a data class is a Kotlin class that auto-generates equals, hashcode, toString etc at compile time - saves time).*

Now I've tried populating it using Spring `RestTemplate`:

```
@Test
fun loadArtist()
{
    val restTemplate = RestTemplate()
    val artist = restTemplate.getForObject(
            "https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=howlin+wolf&entity=allArtist&limit=1", ITunesQueryResults::class.java);
    println("Got artist: $artist")
}
```

It fails with:

```
Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type 
[class vampr.api.service.authorization.facebook.ITunesArtist] 
and content type [text/javascript;charset=utf-8]
```

Fair enough - the JSON object mapper was probably expecting mime-type of `text/json`. Other than telling `RestTemplate` to map to `String::class.java`, and then instantiating an instance of `JacksonObjectMapper` by hand, is there a way to tell my `RestTemplate` to treat the returned mime type as JSON?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of providing defaults for all properties in your data class you can also use this: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin

This Jackson module will allow you to serialize and deserialize Kotlin's data classes without having to worry about providing an empty constructor.

In a Spring Boot Application you can register the module with a `@Configuration` class like so:

```
@Configuration
class KotlinModuleConfiguration {
    @Bean
    fun kotlinModule(): KotlinModule {
        return KotlinModule()
    }
}
```

Other than that you can also use the extension functions mentioned in the documentation to register the module with Jackson.

Besides supporting data classes you will also get support for several classes from the Kotlin stdlib, like Pair for example.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure about Spring, but Jackson needed me to specify that I worked with a Java Bean. You see, Kotlin `data class` is exactly the same as a standard Bean on the byte code level.

Do not forget that Java Bean specification implies an empty constructor (without parameters). A nice way to have it auto-generated is to provide default values for all parameters of your primary constructor.

To serialize an object from Jackson to String:

- The 'get' portion of Java Beans specification is required.

To read a JSON string to object:

- The 'set' portion of the spec is required.
- Additionally the object requires an empty constructor.

Modify the class to include:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
data public class ITunesArtist(var artistName: String? = null, 
    var artistId: Long = -1L, val amgArtistId: String = "id", 
    var artistLinkUrl: URL? = null)
```

- Fields provide defaults in order for there to be an empty constructor.

**Edit:**

Uses the Kotlin Module from @mhlz's (now accepted) answer removes the need to provide a default constructor.

Comment: Yes, that was it, more or less.

Comment: actually I am not sure that fields must be nullable.  What there must be are default values to allow kotlinc to generate an empty constructor.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't test, but I'm 99.999% sure you're right. From memory and it stands to reason.